# WPF ClickOnce install silently without "Unknown publisher" dialog in local interanet

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I've developed a simple wpf application which it has to be installed on all network domain clients computers.
so I added a following command that will affect after user logoff/login:

```
"\\Messenger\Messenger.Application" /install /silent /passive
```

but the problem is when `\\Messenger\Messenger.Application` runs on clients computer this dialog box appears which I want to bypass it. because not all users click on Run and I don't want that.
[image]

how can I install this application without take confirm of user and run the install procedure silently?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to sign the application to remove the "Unknown Publisher" warning.  To do this, buy a code signing certificate and sign your application.

I'm guessing that by default Windows won't allow silent installs for applications that haven't been signed.